# C# memory profile

Tags: c#, memory, profile

I'm trying to perform some memory profiling on an applications that is accumulating large amounts of memory.

I have found this tool (CLRProfiler):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx

But it does not seem to be working. When I run it, it sits forever at "Waiting for application to start common language runtime".

Any other suggestions on how I can profile memory in C#?

Comment: Are you using the correct version? Keep in mind there is a 32-bit version and a 64-bit one. This has to match your application build settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out Redgate:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

Answer (score 4):

If you work with W7 or Vista, start it as administrator (File->ContextMenu->Run as Administrator). As already said by others, also check out to use the correct version.

Comment: @Zenox: Do you have selected the right clr-version in the Target CLR Version-Combobox? Up to .net 3.51, select V2 Desktop CLR, above, use the V4. Do you have the latest clr profiler  (V4)? I remember I had the same problem as you but starting it with elevated rights has solved the problem (ensure that you don't have another instance of clr profiler running). However after I had CLR profiler get up to work, I switched to http://memprofiler.com/ Really impressive this tool...

Comment: For me I needed a combination of this answer and the comment above which is interesting because my colleague can run it without having to chose administrator and can leave it with v4 of the CLR for running the exact same application so it seems a bit random!

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using the wrong version!

The new (v4.0) version is at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273, which is working well for me (and it's free).

Answer (score 3):

If your project is set to build x86, then you have to use the 32 bit version, even if your OS is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a commercial product like [ants memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) (red-gate) or [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) (jetbrains).

Both are very easy to get started with.