# How can i know the source of memory increasing in my code while runing it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I know it's a stupid question, but when i run my program which contains threading , i find that the memory(VM, and Memory used) by the application in the Task manager is increasing regarding that my threads are stopped at that moment, so i wonder if there's any way to know the source of this, or just know at which line the application is compiling now? .
i used the thread watch window but i didn't get any useful information ragarding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CLR Profiler application to get snapshots of your memory consumption. Then you'll be able to identify the source of your issue.

CLR Profiler is free and available here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be2d842b-fdce-4600-8d32-a3cf74fda5e1

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure your program is using excessive memory then getting your hands on a [memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144084/c-memory-profile) would be a good first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Its worth noting that the memory profiler does not directly map to the memory(VM, and Memory used) or [Working Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684891%28VS.85%29.aspx) counter in Task Manager.

> The working set of a program is a
>   collection of those pages in its
>   virtual address space that have been
>   **recently referenced**. It includes both
>   shared and private data. The shared
>   data includes pages that contain all
>   instructions your application
>   executes, including those in your DLLs
>   and the system DLLs. As the working
>   set size increases, memory demand
>   increases.

If memory serves the Memory Profiler will look at private bytes are which represent the actual memory that you are using.

Also See the section **A comment on performance counters and how not to use taskmanager** in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/09/06/742568.aspx) from Tess Ferrandez