# Ram optimization SDK like RAMRush, for image processing

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, ram

I have a problem in my application, it needs a heavy memory optimization, but for now i have to deliver a test version of the application, i need something like "ramrush" as api can called from my application without any executables, Ramrush is solving my problem magically now, but i can't deliver it with my app.

Comment: *Ram optimization SDK* It's called a programmer.

Comment: You are right, but i have no time to optimize heaps and heaps of non optimized image processing code, i will do the optimization in the very soon feature, but i need something to rescue me for the test version i will deliver today.

Comment: May I ask what image processing framework do you use? There are frameworks that allow memory optimization, and there are frameworks that don't.

Comment: Vote to close: It is unlikly you can find magical wand here... And it is very unclear what you are really looking for.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov perhaps give some time to let OP provide more details. (apparently after the "delivery" day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the OP's immediate needs (even if it's a bit late today)

- [C# memory profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144084/c-sharp-memory-profile)
- [Microsoft DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798), see [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/09/06/capturing-a-memory-dump-using-debugdiag-1-2.aspx)

---

There are two levels of memory optimization in image processing code.

- At the easier level, the programmer tries to delete image objects that are no longer needed, as frequently and early as possible (i.e. after every line of code).
- The more difficult level requires implementing some image processing steps as memory-efficient pipelines.

One example:

```
class RgbToGray : ImageSource
{
    private ImageSource m_src;
    public RgbToGray(ImageSource src)
    {
        m_src = src;
    }
    public void GetPixels(int x0, int y0, int rectWidth, int rectHeight, out Pixel[,] result)
    {
        // omitted: validate parameters
        Pixel[,] temp = new Pixel[rectHeight, rectWidth];
        m_src.GetPixels(x0, y0, rectWidth, rectHeight, out temp);
        for (int y = y0; y < y0 + rectHeight; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = x0; x < x0 + rectWidth; ++x)
            {
                result[y,x] = SomeCalculation(temp[y,x]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In this example, the `RgbToGray` performs an image processing on-demand, without requiring its own permanent memory usage, but instead relies on a temporary buffer. For this implementation to work, the caller must call `GetPixels` with a particular "buffer granularity" which must be smaller than the full image size, in order to achieve the memory-saving effect.

(The particular framework I have in mind is [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654(v=vs.85).aspx), but similar ideas can be found in many other frameworks such as [OpenCV's `MatExpr`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html) template.)

Apparently, not all frameworks allow such optimization.

Comment: Best answer mainly for Microsoft DebugDiag, it is awwwwwwwesome